# How to check if req.params is numbers?

Tags: express

In express.js, all req.params are passed in strings.

30 will be passed in as "30"

Thirty will be passed in as "Thirty"

In such case, how would I write a condition that knows the second case is a string, and the first case actually a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to convert it to Numeric type by either using Number or parseInt.

You will then be able to determine if its a number or not using the isNaN function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest pulling in a parsing library, like [skipper](https://github.com/sailshq/skipper) or [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), to parse for you. Then you can check the type using `typeof`. This is an option if you don't want to check errors when type checking conversions.

Comment: I've tried with body-parser and no it does not show "number" upon typeof